# need some clarifications on GSEvent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, jailbreak

I am looking at the file attached here [GSEvent.h:](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/GraphicsServices/GSEvent.h)

I am interesting to know the following params when the user press the screen.
i.e like pathPressure pathMajorRadius pathProximity etc.. (I  do not want to set these values by myself, but to receive them from the user when he/she press the screen.)

```
typedef struct GSPathInfo {
    unsigned char pathIndex;        // 0x0 = 0x5C
    unsigned char pathIdentity;     // 0x1 = 0x5D
    unsigned char pathProximity;    // 0x2 = 0x5E
    CGFloat pathPressure;               // 0x4 = 0x60
    CGFloat pathMajorRadius;        // 0x8 = 0x64
    CGPoint pathLocation;           // 0xC = 0x68
    GSWindowRef pathWindow;         // 0x14 = 0x70
} GSPathInfo;   // sizeof = 0x18.
```

If I am looking down below the file (GSEvent.h)

```
GSPathInfo GSEventGetPathInfoAtIndex(GSEventRef event, CFIndex index);
```

I was wonder what I need to put in the `GSEventRef event` and `CFIndex index`

So I searched for `GSEventRef` scrolling to the top of the file I saw it is a pointer to `__GSEvent`

```
typedef struct __GSEvent* GSEventRef;
```

I am stuck here, what event do I create and how ...

```
GSEventRef* eventRef = malloc(sizeof(GSEventRef));
```

Or I need to do something like

```
__GSEvent* GSEventRef = malloc(sizeof(__GSEvent));
```

After allocating memory how do I set it ? I mean what value should I set for it?

Comment: These APIs are private; only continue if you understand that this code will ban your app from the App Store.